# regex to match file names blahblah_200901.csv (yyyymm)

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, match, filenames

I've been tinkering with regex to match file names that look like:

```
blahblah_200901.csv (2009, January)
blahblah_201512.csv (2015, December)
```

I have a function that passes in from_year, to_year, from_month, to_month so I can grab ranges but I'm having difficulty with a correct regex. The month field is specified by two digits (i.e. 01 to 12).

```
import os, re
for f in os.listdir("/path/dir"):
   if re.match(x,f):
   print (f)
```

Having trouble with the correct x in the above code.

Comment: `r"blahblah_(19|20)\d{2}(1[0-2]|0[1-9])"` will match months (01-12) in any year in the 20th and 21st century.

Comment: how do I control the regex by my year and month input variables? I want to be able to match a subset of all possibilities where the subset is defined by the year (from, to) and month (from to) variables.

Comment: I see. A regex pattern that covers a date range will be mighty complex. The kind of if-else logic involved will be easier and more cleanly solved by parsing the filenames and comparing the appropriate bits...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest would be to not do any matching at all; instead you'd have the first and last filename, and see that the value fits between the 2:

```
start = 'blahblah_{:04}{:02}'.format(from_year, from_month)
end = 'blahblah_{:04}{:02}'.format(to_year, to_month)

for f in os.listdir('/path/dir'):
    if start <= f <= end:
        print(f)
```

---

If the prefix varies, or the regular expression is more complicated, you can use capturing groups to get the date parts, then convert them to integer:

```
m = re.match('blahblah(\d{4})(\d{2})', f)
if m:
    year = int(m.group(1))
    month = int(m.group(2))

    if (from_year, from_month) <= (year, month) <= (to_year, to_month):
        print(f)
```